# Turn off autocomplete in Sublime REPL in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

When I type in the Sublime Repl console (Python) and hit return to run the command I am getting super annoying autocomplete taking over and changing the command.

How do I turn this off in the SublimeRepl console?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look for, and edit, the following in the SublimeRepl `.sublime-settings` file.  Preferably, add the `"auto_complete": false` to your SublimeRepl user settings.

```
"repl_view_settings": {
        "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
        "auto_indent": true,
        "smart_indent": true,
        "spell_check": false,
        "indent_subsequent_lines": false,
        "detect_indentation": false,
        "auto_complete": true,
        "line_numbers": true,
        "gutter": true
    },
```

Comment: I'm trying this and there is no way to make it work. I tried both in the user settings and the package settings and the **super** aggressive autocomplete is still on. Can it be some other package that's doing this or only the Sublime REPL acts in the iPython shell?

Comment: @jbssm: Remember that iPython has its own autocomplete. You can turn this off by editing `server_autocomplete` in [this file](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/blob/master/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu) on your SublimeREPL install.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an exact answer to your question, but it might help - and it showed up in my search results for disabling auto complete in Sublime Text. There are more options you can change besides just "auto_complete"; for instance, I found this:

```
// Automatically close HTML and XML tags when </ is entered.
"auto_close_tags": true,
```

**Also**, *check your installed packages* for anything that will auto complete.